# How do i set the value in List<E>'s constructor parameters in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, pojo

I have created a pojo class of `Account` in which there is an array of `Address` class. I want to set the value of `address`'s parameter from my main fragment. How do I able to set? Please look ahead my code of `Account` model, `Address` Model and main fragment where I set the data of account model.

Account model (POJO)

```
class Account(
          var OrganizationName: String?,
          var Addresses: List<Address>?,) : Serializable {

constructor() : this(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)}
```

Address Model (POJO)

```
class Address(
var Id: Int?,

var Name: String?,
var AddressLine1: String?,
var AddressLine2: String?,
var City: String?,
var Locality: String?,
var State: String?,
var ZipCode: Int?,
):Serializable
```

Main Fragment class where i set the details of Account and Address class parameters.

```
  class AccountDetailsFragment constructor
  (onCheckChanged: OnCheckChanged, changeTabs: ChangeTabs) : BaseFragment() {override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_details, container, false)


    return view
}

 fun getFilledData(account: Account): Account {

    account.OrganizationName = "name"

    // How do i insert the value for address's parameters here.

    return account


}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up all you are using wrong naming convention for variables. [Read more here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

```
fun getFilledData(account: Account): Account {

    account.OrganizationName = "name"

    val addresses = ArrayList<Address>()
    for(i in 0..10){

        //create and  insert your multiple addresses here
        val address  = Address(i,"name $i","line1 $i","line2 $i ","city $i","locality $i","state $i ", i)

        addresses.add(address)
    }
    //assign list to account
    account.Addresses = addresses

    return account
}
```